# Where can I find good information about database and filesystem design?

Tags: database, algorithm, database-design, data-structures, filesystems

I need to design some data structures for something that's roughly a cross between a database and a file system. In fact there's a large overlap in the design of file systems and databases. I've done some work on both, not very in-depth, but still, I have some idea about the topics. However I need more information and I am wondering if there's a good overview of design concepts out there. Things like overviews of algorithms, data structures and the like. The advantages of different types of trees or hash tables for key lookup. Perhaps some information about data ordering an alignment. In short, the experiences of other people in implementing filesystems and databases that would help the next person avoid the same mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Gray wrote a book titled "Transaction Processing: Concepts and Techniques" - [http://www.amazon.com/Transaction-Processing-Concepts-Techniques-Management/dp/1558601902](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558601902) - which covers a great deal of what you would need to build your own database.

One starting point for file systems would be [http://www.amazon.com/The-Design-UNIX-Operating-System/dp/0132017997](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) - but I suspect you would have to chase down individual papers or Linux source code to keep up with the variety of different file systems created since then.

Comment: The first book looks promising, I'll have to skim through it though. The second book is outdated for my purposes. It only gives the basics, and while it would be of much value to a total novice, I'll have to continue looking. Thank you.